# Rails nested model forms: on load rather than on click

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, nested-forms

So I have this on click method to add nested form and it works perfectly.

```
$(document).on 'click', 'form .add_fields', (event) ->
  time = new Date().getTime()
  regexp = new RegExp($(this).data('id'), 'g')
  $(this).before($(this).data('fields').replace(regexp, time))
  event.preventDefault()
```

But onload I need to fire the above envent once and then on click it should fire the event as well. So I added the code below

```
$(document).on 'click', 'form .add_fields', (event) ->
  time = new Date().getTime()
  regexp = new RegExp($(this).data('id'), 'g')
  $(this).before($(this).data('fields').replace(regexp, time))
  event.preventDefault()

$(document).on 'load', 'form .add_fields', (event) ->
  time = new Date().getTime()
  regexp = new RegExp($(this).data('id'), 'g')
  $(this).before($(this).data('fields').replace(regexp, time))
  event.preventDefault()
```

Event after adding on load event above, it doesn't fire the event. But on click event still works and add nested forms perfectly. How can I make it work?

Comment: try to change your on load js code as: $(document).load (event) ->

Comment: if my answer was useful please consider selected as accepted.

Comment: Hey any news??? was my answer useful? select it as accepted, that's how the community works...

Comment: Man, Im still waiting for you to mark my answer, I took some time answering you...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, your event is not right, you need `page:load`, just `load` won't work due to turbolinks. Also you are repeating yourself... Allow me give you a better implementation:

```
addNewNestedItem = ->
    $('form .add_fields').on 'click', (event) ->
        time = new Date().getTime()
        regexp = new RegExp($(this).data('id'), 'g')
        $(this).before($(this).data('fields').replace(regexp, time))
        event.preventDefault()

$(document).ready addNewNestedItem
$(document).on 'page:load', addNewNestedItem
```

The above for sure will work, and it is well written.

Comment: well but I can't help you if you do not provide more details, please check that the code you use is well indented... Also check for JavaScript errors in the console, update your answer with more details. Is the click action working?

Comment: Click action works but on load action is not working

Comment: ok but, you are saying it is working with the implementation I gave you? or with your implementation?

Comment: also do the following: add a console.log in the `addNewNestedItem()` function, like `console.log 'if you can see this, it is running'` then reload the page and check the JavaScript console in your browser, let me know if you can see the text printed in the console.